# Pass Index Number between UITableView List segue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5, segue

When I click a certain list item in my UITableView, I want to pass the index of the item that I clicked on to the next detailed view.

This is my relevant code so far:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    HomeworkDetails *view =  [[HomeworkDetails alloc] init];


    int lastIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];
    NSLog(@"%u", lastIndex);

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"HomeworkDetailsSegue" sender:self];
    view.currentIndex = lastIndex;

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

At this point, I can successfully move on to the next ViewController (HomeworkDetails) but the information is not passed through. I am trying to accomplish this by doing `view.currentIndex = lastIndex;` but this is not working. How else can I do this? Sorry if I missed anything; I am a beginner at iOS development.

With suggestions:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    HomeworkDetails *view =  [[HomeworkDetails alloc] init];


    int lastIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];
    NSLog(@"%u", lastIndex);

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"HomeworkDetailsSegue" sender:self];
    view.currentIndex = lastIndex;

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];



}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"HomeworkDetailsSegue"]) {

        // note that "sender" will be the tableView cell that was selected
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; //**error**


        HomeworkDetails *vc = (HomeworkDetails*)[segue destinationViewController];
        vc.currentIndex = indexPath.row;
    }
}
```

[image: Error from Compiler]

Comment: Is `currentIndex` meant to be a property on your tableView controller or on the segue's destination viewController?

Comment: it is a property on the destination ViewController. sorry for the confusion. Also, to test, I am basically setting a TextView on the destination controller to this property, but it is always 0.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you are describing can best be done in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.  In your storyboard, make sure your `HomeworkDetailsSegue` segue is set up between your tableView's prototype cell and the destination view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{    
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"HomeworkDetailsSegue"]) {

        // note that "sender" will be the tableView cell that was selected
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        HomeworkDetails *vc = (HomeworkDetails*)[segue destinationViewController];
        vc.currentIndex = indexPath.row;
    }
}
```

Also, as a matter of style, I would recommend renaming your HomeworkDetails class to HomeworkDetailsViewController.  Doing this follows Apple's conventions more closely and makes it clearer what the class represents.

Comment: I get an error on this line: 'self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];' and the compiler says that tableView is not a property of the current interface. and also, what do you mean "make sure it is set up between your tableView's cells and the destination view controller"

I suspect this could be the problem; as of now, the segue is between my currentViewController and the nextViewController...how do I make it from the tableView instead?

Comment: The `prepareForSegue:` method should be a part of your tableview controller's class, not the HomeworkDetails class.

As for setting up the segue, click on your tableview's prototype cell in the storyboard so the cell is selected.  Then hold down the Control key while you drag from that cell to your destination view controller.  Finally, set the Identifier label for your segue in the properties inspector to "HomeworkDetailsSegue".

Comment: It is part of my original class as I believe it should be. It is in the class where I originally initiate my segue. All I am saying is that right now the segue goes from ViewController -> Destination ViewController in the storyboard. Is that the way it should be or should it be from UITableView -> Destination ViewController and how do I do this? Also, the error it's giving is Property indexPathForCell is not found on object of type "HomeworkPage". HomeworkPage is my original ViewController that contains the tableView.

Comment: Sorry, i just saw your comment edit. Let me try that out and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Okay, so I changed it so now the segue is from the cell to the next ViewController. However, I am still placing this method inside the first ViewController, correct? (As in, the first ViewController that contains the UITableView). It still gives me the same error (see above comment).

Comment: That is correct.  Make sure your target of the `indexPathForCell:` message is `self.tableView` instead of just `self`.

Comment: To my original question, I added code so you can see how my class reflects your changes. can you spot what's wrong?

Comment: this is how my header file looks like if it matters:
@interface HomeworkPage : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    UITableView *homeworkTable;
}

Comment: Aha.  I was assuming you were subclassing UITableViewController.  I see that you have created your own property for the tableview called 'homeworkTable'  Change `self.tableView` in my example code to `self.homeworkTable` and your code should compile.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10105/discussion-between-kgrover-and-jonkroll)

Comment: am I still supposed to declare sender:self when executing the segue?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
    returns null. What does this indicate?

Comment: if indexPath is null, check to make sure that your `homeworkTable` property is connected to the tableView in your storyboard correctly via an IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the index property in your new view prior to segueing to it with performSegueWityIdentifier. And to take it a step further, best practice coding convention calls for setting up the new view using the standard [prepareForSegue](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue%3asender%3a) method.